# Error with creating an add-on with heroku

Tags: java, heroku

I'm trying to create an add-on with Heroku, but I'm getting this error:

> that add-on plan is only available to select users.

Anyone can help me solve this error?

Comment: What add-on are you trying to create?

Comment: You should include more information about when and where you're encountering this error. Refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve